# Open a reportViewer in printing view by default

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am loading in reportViewer named reportViewer1 a crystal report from a Form in C# .Net 4.0 in Visual Studio 2012.

I want that when the form shows to the user, the crystal report were showing in printing view by default.
Now the report is showing in the standard view, and I have to clic the button marked in red on that image to go the printing view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuGKN.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have confused two reporting technologies, namely [SAP Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/) which opens rpt files and [Microsoft Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885185%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which opens rdlc files.

The image that you have attached shows a Microsoft Report Viewer's bar. To have the printing view by default when the viewer shows up add the following line of code

```
ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```