# How I could change report presentation in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm loading a rdlc report in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms:

[image]

How I could show the report with this presentation by programming in C# :
[image]

This presentation only can be shown with pressing printing designer button:
[image: print designer button]

Comment: You mean Print Preview?

Comment: @AbdisamadKhalif Yes, but I found the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Open a reportViewer in printing view by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169714/open-a-reportviewer-in-printing-view-by-default)

```
ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```